# How to make the car run in a path

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am a beginner in canvas game development and I have made a simple car game where now the car can move towards the target in a diagonal movement like below:

```
var Car = (function(_super) {
    __extends(Car, _super);

    function Car(position, target) {
      if (target === void 0) {
        target = null;
      }
      var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
      _this.position = position;
      _this.target = target;
      _this.hitCount = 0;
      _this.image = GameImage.getImage("hero");
      _this.speed = 9;
      Car.all.push(_this);
      return _this;
    }
    var hitCount=0;
    Car.prototype.main = function() {
      var angle = angleBetweenTwoPoints(this.target.position, this.position);
      var cos = Math.cos(degreeToRadian(angle)) * -1;
      var sin = Math.sin(degreeToRadian(angle));
      var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
      this.angle = angle;
      this.position.x += cos * this.speed;
      this.position.y -= sin * this.speed;
      if (distance(this.position, this.target.position) < 10 && this.image == GameImage.getImage("hero") ) {
        this.target.position.x = Math.random() * mainCanvas.width;
        this.target.position.y = Math.random() * mainCanvas.height;
        this.hitCount++;
        console.log(hitCount);
        ctx.fillText("points : " + hitCount, 32, 32);
         this.changeImage = true;
          _this.speed = 3;
        this.changeImageTime = Date.now() + 600; //0.5 sec from now.

        this.image = (this.image == GameImage.getImage("hero"))? GameImage.getImage("hero_other") : GameImage.getImage("hero");

      }

      if(this.changeImage){
      if(Date.now() > this.changeImageTime){
        this.changeImage = false;
        _this.speed = 9;
        this.image = (this.image == GameImage.getImage("hero_other"))? GameImage.getImage("hero") : GameImage.getImage("hero_other");
      }
    }


    };
    return Car;
  }
```

So now I need to move the car in a order (something like turn left turn right then reach target).So which is the easiest way to move my car in a way that without making much changes in existing pattern.
In case of additional code my [pen of game](https://codepen.io/RKR3/project/editor/ANBVpA/)
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

### Way point path following

To add way point  path following you need to create a path array which you can add to the car object.

The path object holds way points. Way points are added to the end of the path, to get the next way point you check if there are any available by checking `path.hasWayPoints` and the call `path.nextWayPoint` You can provide a target position object `path.nextWayPoint(position)` or have it create one `const position = path.nextWayPoint()`

You move the car to its current target, when close check for another way point, if there is one set the target.position to the next way point. If no way points do what you normally do at target.

#### The path object

```
const path = {
    points : null,
    hasWayPoints : false,
    addPoint (point) {
       this.points.push({x : point.x, y : point.y}); // copy point as object comes
                                                     // from unknown source.
       this.hasWayPoints = true;
       return this;
    },
    nextWayPoint (retPoint = {}) {
       var p;
       if (this.points.length > 0) {
          p = this.points.shift(); 
          retPoint.x = p.x;
          retPoint.y = p.y;
          this.hasWayPoints = this.points.length > 0;
       }
       return retPoint;
    }    
}


function createPath () {
     return Object.assign({}, path, {points : []});
}
```

#### Using the path object

Where you create a `Car` you add the path object

```
_this.path = createPath();
if (target !== null) {
    _this.path.addPoint(target.position);
}
```

You add more way points as follows (cringe so bad having _this and this)

```
this.path.addPoint({x : 100, y : 200});
```

When the `Car` get close to the target

```
// your code line 446
if (distance(this.position, this.target.position) < 10 && this.image == GameImage.getImage("hero") ) {
```

Check if there are way points

```
    if (this.path.hasWayPoints) {
        this.path.nextWayPoint(this.target.position);
    } else {
        // your code from 447 - 457
    }
```

I leave it up to you to add new way points for the car's next target.

That is the minimum non invasive way to add way point path following to your code.

Comment: Just a clarification, so the  way points should be predefined in the `this.path.addPoint({x : 100, y : 200});`. but in my case it should get the way point from the target and how to predefine it?